# Why is my DC-DC buck converter consuming 8mA of current with no load connected?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck

I am using a [TPS5430 buck converter](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps5430.pdf) on my PCB which is converting 12V to 8V. If I shutdown the buck converter using the enable pin it consumes only a few micro amps but if I leave it enabled with no load connected it consumes about 8mA constantly.

According to the datasheet quiescent current should be 4.4mA (max).

My questions are:

- Is it normal?
- Is it consumption or power loss?
- How can I avoid/fix it?

Schematic:

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: Your voltage divider is consuming 0.67mA. What does the datasheet say about efficiency at such low currents? Sometimes the efficiency is only good at higher currents, but terrible at no load. If it was 18%, this could add up to 8mA total, possibly.

Comment: According to DS, Quiescent current is 4.4 mA (max) when (among other things) VSENSE is at 2V, not switching and PH opened. Your circuit isnt similar to theirs test conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i think you are right about the efficiency being terrible at no load. 
Basically, i want to power an STM32 through a 12V battery. What would be the best option here for me?
Do I use an LDO or another buck converter which provides less output current (perhaps 500mA max or 1A) ?

Comment: The TPS5430 has quite high quiescent current. It might be a good idea to look into micropower buck converters; Maxim and LT (both now owned by Analog) have a good selection. Just pay attention to quiescent current, and if possible try to simulate them (both of the aforementioned manufacturers have good simulation models for most of their parts) to check how they'll act before designing a PCB.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you missed this bit of information: -

[image]

So when it says "not switching" it likely means the device is operating in burst mode on no-load: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-parabolic-voltage-control-strategy-for-burst-mode-Zhang-Born/49d5df53118a333e8b7ba1986ada46367f8b3076).

And, in particular, the current specified is measured in-between bursts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Not switching means no load connected but the IC is active?

Comment: @NishantNidaria it's basically telling you what the current consumption is when operating in burst mode in a no-load scenario. And specifically it means the current drawn in the dead-time between bursts. Do you understand burst mode?

Comment: Yes i understand burst mode, so, for instance, when i go from 12V to 3.3V and connect an STM32 with it, it consumes about 5-6mA and during deep sleep mode it consumes roughly 4-5mA. it is a normal operation? and the consumption is as per the datasheet?

Comment: I have no idea how much current is taken by the STM32.

Answer (score 5):

The datasheet specifies 4.4mA max:

> VSENSE = 2 V, Not switching, PH pin open

So the circuit is not shut down, but neither is it operating. That's not what you are testing.